# JQGrid Time reservation...selecting multiple columns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, calendar, multiple-columns

I want to develop a reservation application where we display columns representing time with intervals of 1hr. Is it possible to drag and select multiple coloumns (8:00 - 11:00) to make a reservation.And also only certain coloumns which already do not have a reservation should be editable.

Is this functionality possible with JQGrid? If not do you have any other recommendations?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Even if this functionality is technically possible, I am not sure that jqGrid is the appropriate control.

It seems that [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) would be a better choice for a time reservation system, although you will have to write your own code to prevent overlapping events. There are live examples and API documentation on their site to let you evaluate the capabilities of the calendar.